# why android Lint doesn't give a warning when use android:orientation in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout

We know RelativeLayout doesn't support android:orientation attribute, but why Lint doesn't give a warning if we use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See, it gave the warn already:

[image]

Comment: click the "light" icon, Lint will give you the current info? I only see the override the resource and reset to the default namespace.